Is it UB immediately assigning an invalid address to a pointer?
This question applies to both C and C++. I always thought it was OK to assign any value to a pointer, as long as when you dereference that pointer that it points to "valid" memory (memory used by your process, or allocated in some way). However I found out that:
int arr[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
int *p = arr + 5;  // undefined behavior for indexing out of bounds even if not dereferenced

The rule in the specification is that the p pointer is allowed to pointer to at most one byte past the end of the memory within which the array is contained, no more, so arr + 4, while pointing out-of-bounds, is only one byte past and so isn't UB, however arr + 5 is UB.
Does this mean that a pointer pointing to any memory that doesn't point to something you've allocated is UB? For example:
int* p = 0xDDDD;

Assuming 0xDDDD is outside the address where your program resides and isn't part of anything you've allocated? I'm not getting whether arr + 5 is UB because it's an invalid address to dereference or if it's specifically the "INCREMENTING" that makes it UB? In other words arr + 5 is UB because you're "INCREMENTING" past valid memory and therefore risking integer overflow, but int* p = 0xFFFF (or any random address) is OK?

Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. They are different languages and their rules are different. Even when something is defined (or not defined) in both of them, the rules making it so may be different. Pick one tag and delete the other.

If what you are saying about 0xDDDD is UB, wouldn't int* p = 0 be UB also?

I believe it is specifically the invalid pointer math arr + 5 that is UB.

@DrewDormann I told them that in the previous question.

It is explicitly stated for pointer arithmetic only

@edtheprogrammerguy Converting 0 to a pointer has specific behavior that doesn't apply to any other value (and only applies it the original expression is an integral constant expression).

"Undefined behavior" means that the C Standard does not define what will happen. It doesn't mean the operation is invalid, or might be integer overflow, or an illegal address.

See answers on this question for the standard's rules about pointer arithmetic and out-of-bounds

@WeatherVane  Ohhh, all this time I assumed UB was necessarily bad and dangerous, but it's just that the standard doesn't define what happens. Any good compiler would obviously be designed in a way that doesn't do something dangerous or stupid in the presence of UB, so it's not necessarily bad.

@Zebrafish all this time I assumed UB was necessarily bad and dangerous UB is bad if you require consistent results.  Once you invoke UB, consistent results can not be guaranteed.  Accepting that your code might not always work as intended is an awfully low standard to write code to.

@Zebrafish A compiler usually sees UB as an opportunity for optimization. Which can lead to something stupid or dangerous.

Let's take your example. If you have uint8_t x[2], and then somewhere in the code you write x + a, the compiler might decide that add instruction is not necessary here because x only has two elements, so a can be assumed to be 0 or 1 only. And will replace add with conditional inc. So you see, the result of such an arithmetic will be unexpected in some cases.

@EugeneSh. you can legally do x+2 to create a one-past-end pointer in that case

@RyanHaining You are right. I guess the example can be fixed by changing it to x[1]

Conversion of an integer to a pointer is allowed with a cast, however such a conversion is implementation defined.
Section 6.3.2.3p5 of the C standard details this:

An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously
specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be
correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced
type, and might be a trap representation.

So there's no guarantee that dereferencing such a pointer will be valid.  In practice, this is only the case in embedded environments where particular addresses are well-known.

For the embedded case, it is also common to have something like volatile uint32_t* base = 0x1234; and then dereferencing *(base + index) assuming base is the start address of some memory-mapped peripheral with multiple registers. This can be interpreted as UB per the standard. But then we can argue, that there is an "object" at these addresses, even though it is not "known" to the C implementation.
